# Why my Java code print something I didn't code?

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, error-handling

So I have my main code like this

```
import ExprUtils;
import Expr;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SATDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            Expr e = ExprUtils.parseFrom(System.in);
            System.out.println(ExprUtils.checkSAT(e) ? "SAT" : "UNSAT");            
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }        
    }
}
```

And my ExprUtils code like this

```
import Expr;

public class ExprUtils
{    
    public static boolean checkSAT(Expr expr)
    {
        return true; //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("implement this");
    }
}
```

My IDE is VSCode and my OS is Ubuntu. I have the latest version of java and maven. When I run below command on VSCode terminal, it outputs my commented error. I thought it should output SAT.

```
java -cp target/hw2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar edu.utexas.cs.alr.SATDriver < resources/sample-inputs/ex1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: implement this
        at edu.utexas.cs.alr.util.ExprUtils.checkSAT(ExprUtils.java:32)
        at edu.utexas.cs.alr.SATDriver.main(SATDriver.java:16)
```

For your info, regardless what my input value from `resources/sample-inputs/ex1`, it doesn't matter because I set my function to always true, so you can also ignore `Expr e`,`parseFrom`, and `Expr expr` because it won't change the return value of my function. Also you don't have to worry about what's inside `Expr`, it doesn't contains any printing debug and won't change the return value.

However it outputs my error code that I have commented and the error notification line is exactly the same (i.e. `System.out.println` line is on line 16 and `return true` line is on line 32). I don't know why this can happen, I am very confuse.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it might sound obvious, but I just need to check. Are you sure you are running the right code? How did you compile it? Can you say will complete certainty that your code is inside of `target/hw2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`?

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure. I have checked it multiple times.

Comment: Can you add how you compiled it to your question? Either your code is not in fact being compiled the way you expect or something in your build configuration is not set up correctly. Comments can't be executed as code. There are no special edge cases.

Comment: I think you missed to compile the new version of the file. Or you are running old copy of jar.
I suspect the old copy is still there in the jar which still contains: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("implement this");

try deleting the jar, and rerun it. Start fresh.
if you are using maven, make sure you run mvn clean